# how to fail a yaml pipline if ps1 script has errors

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a yaml template file that contains a PowerShell file as a task. the pipeline on executing the powershell file if errors are detected the pipeline should fail. i am look for option on how can i make the ps1 fail.

I tried 2 options :

1. ErrorActionPreference : Stop
2. failOnStandardError: true (fails pipelines on warnings in ps1)

I am looking to see if there are any other options to have the pipeline failed on only error in ps1 rather than using if condition in the ps1.

The ps1 file makes a couple of azure powershell request to get and provision roles

```
parameters:
- name: ServiceConnection
  default: ''

steps:
- checkout: self
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Fail script on errors
  enabled: true
  inputs:
    ErrorActionPreference : Stop
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.ServiceConnection }}
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'scriptPath'
    scriptPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/powershell.ps1'
```

Comment: have you tried the `failOnStandardError` input ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines#inputs

Comment: I did try 'failOnStandardError -true' the pipeline fails on also warnings

Comment: Then you try to return `exit 1` when an error happen in your script

Comment: have you tried to add `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` into your powershell script?